# Hakyll generates weird HTML - can anybody explain reason?

Tags: html, markup, template-engine, hakyll

I use Hakyll to generate some documentation and I noticed that it has a weird way of closing the HTML tags in the code it generates.

There was a page where they said that you must generate the markup as they do, or the layout of your page will be broken under some conditions, but I can't find it now.

I created a small test page (code below) which has one red layer with the "normal" HTML markup, and a yellow layer with markup similar to what hakyll generates.

I can't see any diference in Firefox between the two divs.

Can anybody explain if what they say is true?

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- NORMAL STYLE -->
<div style="background: red">
<p>Make available the code from the library you added to your application. Again, the way to do this varies between languages (from adding import statements in python to adding a jar to the classpath for java)</p>
<p>Create an instance of the client and, in your code, make calls to it through this instance's methods.</p>
</div>
<!-- HAKYLL STYLE -->
<div style="background: yellow"
><p
>Make available the code from the library you added to your application. Again, the way to do this varies between languages (from adding import statements in python to adding a jar to the classpath for java)</p
><p
>Create an instance of the client and, in your code, make calls to it through this instance's methods.</p
></div
>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: It looks like this question was edited so that the distinction between the normal style and Hakyll style was lost. Just mentioning it for anyone else who was confused like I was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) that's generating the HTML code. There's a good explanation in the Pandoc issue tracker:

http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/issues/detail?id=134

> The reason is
>   because any whitespace (including newline and tabs) between HTML tags will cause the
>   browser to insert a space character between those elements. It is far easier on the
>   machine logic to leave these spaces out, because then you don't need to think about
>   the possible ways that the HTML text formatting could be messing with the browser adding
>   extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There are times when stripping the white space between two tags will make a difference, particularly when dealing with inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

I ran tidy over it and it fixed the unusual linebreaks.